# How to customize header template in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, ios, mobile, xamarin

I'm creating an application in Xamarin forms which requires customized header. Is it possible to customize the header with background image in Xamarin forms?

Comment: What headers are you talking about?

Comment: I mean the navigation bar.

Comment: You can change that in the theme or set altogether different items into the Action bar of android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably look at this solution from the Xamarin Forum - [NavigationBar Background Image Render Android](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/44586/navigationbar-background-image-renderer-android), This seems to be a working cross platform solution for both iOS and Android. It would work by creating a custom render, which is the best way to go for any customization in X.F

**Android :**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ContentPage), typeof(ContentPageRenderer))]
    namespace MyApp.Renderers
    {
        public class ContentPageRenderer : PageRenderer
        {
            protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
            {
                    base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
                    var actionBar = ((Activity)Context).ActionBar;
                    actionBar.SetBackgroundDrawable(Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.YourImageInDrawable));
            }
        }
    }
```

**iOS :**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomNavigationPage), typeof(BlueNavigationRenderer))]
    namespace MobileCRM.iOS.Renderers
    {
        public class BlueNavigationRenderer : NavigationRenderer
        {

            public override void ViewDidLoad()
            {
                base.ViewDidLoad();

                this.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.FromPatternImage(UIImage.FromFile("topbar_bg@2x.png"));
             }
          }
     }
```